# Qt cooperating with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, qt, codeblocks

What is the workflow etc when I want to create GUI in Qt but logic in Code::Blocks?
It is important to me for the reason that Qt doesn't come with compiler I use on Code::Blocks and I really, really need this compiler gcc 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up Qt Creator to use compiler of you choice.

Go to the Tools->Options menu, click on Tool Chains and add a path to your g++ executable.

Comment: I did that and still cannot compile code which is properly compiled by gcc 4.6.1. It seems to use the old compiler all the time.

Comment: You also need to select the tool chain in project's build settings. Click "Projects" on left side toolbar, then "Build Settins" tab and finally select your compiler from "Tool chain" drop-down list. Make also sure that you added correct executable. In mingw (if that's what you're using) it's mingw32-g++.exe.

Comment: Now I'm getting: Cannot execute '': The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Then double check if the compiler's files are where they're supposed to be. Sorry, but that's all I can help you with. It works for me here, FWIW.

Comment: so you're saying that you actually can plug in different compiler and compile with it? Does your compiler compiles for example for (auto e: collection){cout << e;}?